# MongoDB store JSON String via Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

There are multiple tutorials like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-insert-a-document/) and [this](http://supundharmarathne.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/simple-crud-operations-with-java-and-mongodb-part-1/) which describes saving JSON data using JSON.parse method which returns DBObject. Though it is very simple and brief way of saving JSON data what I wonder is why is there a need to parse the JSON? Can I not directly save my JSON string directly to Mongo without parsing, I see that the mongo shell can do that.

The reason I ask this is because I have thousands of documents in chunks and I may save time by not parsing data!

In a nutshell is there a java method of following form in some drivers

```
Collection coll = new Collection("mycollection");
coll.save("[{datakey1:dataval1},{datakey2:datavalue2},...]");
```

Comment: MongoDB is a BSON store not a JSON store, the console can do it because JSON and JS objects are similar in syntax. I would like to add as well that decoding JSON into your native language objects and then saving it down without any real validation is just asking to be hacked, this is the worst method of destroying any kind of injection protection MongoDBs native querying offers.

Comment: You are right about BSON. Other thing, the data to save is just backup data coming from our RDBMS system. There is no consumer or no "Attacker" to do SQL or script injection

Comment: Ah ok, so you have a scenario where this shouldn't be too terrible. But yea you need to decode first to do this, since it is a import from your RBDMS you might wanna use batch insert here too, it can perform much better than `save`

Comment: So to insert a string like this [[{"hpisymptoms":"of days in past 2 weeks depression free?"},{"hpisymptoms":"*"}]] must I parse it and load it in List<DBObject>? This data is coming from another RDMS already encoded in valid JSON

Comment: I don't believe there is since, of course, MongoDB is not JSON, the reason why the console can do this is because JSON follows JS object syntax. One way this could be made easier is to this via a batch insert script in the terminal, hmmmm maybe

Comment: I am curious why you would consider Mongodb as a backup system for your RDBMS json data.  Wouldn't a dump to file work better for you case since you don't intend to query the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your use case, if you insert a list of DBObject, it will actually result in multiple document in mongodb. This seems to be a strange use case for MongoDB, it could be stored like this:

```
{
   id: 507f191e810c19729de860ea,
   value: '[[{"hpisymptoms":"of days in past 2 weeks depression free?"},{"hpisymptoms":"*"}]]'
}
```

You should only do this if you never intended to query the json data, which is what Mongo is good at.  This sounds like the case because the json data was stored in a RDBMS field.

Comment: Well, this data was stored in RDMS in regular column-rows format, but in the process of sending it from one server to another we are marshalling it as JSON. Once received at the receiver we have to unmarshall it in memory.

Comment: So is the intend to use Mongodb as a JSON cache for your RDBMS?

Comment: I would call it a warehouse

Comment: What do you meant when you said: 'You should only do this if you never intended to query the json data, which is what Mongo is good at.? You mean I should not use MongoDB if my documents are in JSON and they mostly used for querying/search?

Comment: I mean storing Json as an String field is not very useful, as it does not allow you to query or aggregate your data.  It should be saved as an embedded object.